# Differences in Windows and Linux. Using SFML and pointers

Tags: c++, linux, windows, sfml

I just want to know more about cross-platfrom programming. I create game in [SFML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_and_Fast_Multimedia_Library) 2.1 and C++. And I have a problem. This code works under Linux, but it doesn't work under Windows ([MinGW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW)). There is no error, but nothing is drawn.

```
Shop::Shop(): shop_texts() {}
//...

void Shop::draw(App* app)
{
    app->window.draw(shop_texts.getText("btn_playerskins"));
}
```

`shop_texts` returns an `sf::Drawable` object.

And then in App:

```
shop.draw(this);
```

`shop_texts` exists, because I can check e.g position or text (this object contains sf::Text field). What is difference?

Comment: Whats the error? What happens in Windows?

Comment: No errors. Everything works. But it doesn't draw.

Comment: @patys For future reference, simply saying "it doesn't work" is not helpful at all for the rest of us. Specifying the specific issue (along with any relevant error messages) in as much detail as you can is very helpful. I've added the actual issue of "no errors, but doesn't draw" to your question. Feel free to correct or add detail as necessary with the `edit` link at the bottom of your question.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It's my first question.

Comment: Provide a compilable and minimal example, so we can be sure it's not your code or use code from official examples. Next make sure your graphics driver is up to date. Then build in debug mode with a console window and provide use possible errors. Finally, is there a reason you're not using SFML 2.2?